# Xcode 7.1 complains about adHoc provisioning profile for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, adhoc, xcode7.1

I've upgraded to `Xcode 7.1` with no updates in the adHoc provisioning profile I was using. Now, when I archive and export the adHoc binary, I get a warning in `Xcode` saying that some of the devices I have registered in my account are not in the provisioning... I don't undestand that, the warning mentions devices that I don't want to be included in the provisioning, so I didn't included them.

The provisioning was working in `Xcode 7.0.1` before I upgraded, has somebody also found this issue?

Thanks

Comment: When you add new devices, the previous provisioning profile expires. It might show active on developer portal but still you need to update the provisioning profile.

Comment: @BhavukJain I haven't added any new device. In fact, if I archive with Xcode 7.0.1, it takes the provisioning profile with no problem...

Answer (score 0):

Really not, but, for many reasons I re-update the provisioning. Go to your Program page, edit your provisioning to "re-create" it.

In Xcode then, through "Preferences->Accounts" select your account and then "View details" to make sure Xcode downloads them for you.

Remember, as you probably already know, that you need to re-select the provisioning in the "Build Settings" tab for each configuration of your project/targets because they are now new.

Unfortunately ad-hoc provisioning became to me useless because TestFlight is now part of the Apple iTunes Connect and I have no https website to store my certificates and bundles into...

Hope this info help